# how do I kill the windows file protection /SFC window?

Tags: windows-xp

I started up SFC, with SFC /scannow, and it wants a cd.  I don't have one on me right now. I just want to kill the window.

I may run SFC later.  But how do I get rid of it? whether I click retry or cancel it doesn't go.

Comment: fortunately sfc in win7 doesn't ask for a cd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to hit "Cancel" to the lower box in the first screenshot, and then "Cancel" in the upper one, but I can see that if it pulled up another file instantly, you might not be able to do that.

[image]

I then went to Task Manager, right-clicked and clicked "Go To Process", and that brought me to the "winlogon.exe" process, which you CANNOT kill.

[image]

So I logged out thinking that would kill it, but then I logged back in (No Fast User Switching), and it STILL was there.

So on one try, I think I may have what you want: In the past, I have always hit "Cancel" as in the one asking for the CD first, but this time, I hit Cancel for the Main one, and it ended it, leaving the CD one sitting on the screen, and then I canceled that one too. Give that a try.

Comment: You need to look at the processes tab.

Comment: @CGA I gave a solution at the end, but when you click on Go To Process, it takes you to the process tab, but as I explained, you CANNOT kill the winlogon.exe process, which is what is running sfc. Your comment and answer are incorrect as they are impossible.

Comment: @barlop I added ALL the things I did, and HOW I did them, so if my last paragraph did not work for you, you would not need to repeat them.

Comment: Not sure it will work though  since I see it's the windows file protection that's kicking in.

Comment: Yes you're right. I get 2 windows, and if you click cancel in the main window first, then in the window that asks for Retry, then it works. As you said. Accepted and +1.

Comment: @barlop It is just so natural to hit the second one first. I have always done that. I never thought to try to reverse the order. Thank you very much for marking it. I appreciate it.

Comment: That "go to process" thing is an interesting one I hadn't seen it before. I found it was winlogon.exe with process explorer, dragging the shield icon to the window it highlighted that process..and as you say, the process doesn't / can't/perhaps "shouldn't"/doesn't need to be, terminated

Answer (score 1):

:>It is posible save the following code in file naming "CLEAR.VBS"
:>Then call this file through the given command using cmd or batch file
:>please change %CD% to the path to the clear.vbs if it is not the current directory.

START "" WSCRIPT //B "%CD%\CLEAR.VBS" "%CD%.Flag_SafeToDel"

==>This following is the code paste it in notepade and SAVE File AS CLEAR.VBX

```
' Clears WFP message
const win="Windows File Protection"
const wi2="Unable To Locate Component"
set arg=wscript.arguments
if arg.count then
 flg=arg.item(0)
 else WScript.Quit
  wscript.quit
end if
set w=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
set f=wscript.createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
x=999
while x > 0
 if w.appactivate(win) then
  w.sendkeys "{ESC}"
  w.sendkeys "{TAB}{ENTER}"
 end if
 if w.appactivate(wi2) then
  w.sendkeys "{ESC}{TAB}{ENTER}"
 end if
 if f.fileexists(flg) then
  x=45
  f.deletefile(flg)
 end if
 wscript.sleep 333
 x=x-1
wend
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ending the SFC process in the Task Manager. It can be access via alt+control+delete, or right clicking on the taskbar.

Comment: The traditional expression for the 3 finger salute, which one would use to restart after a BSOD, is ctrl-alt-delete